# Direct Email to userid

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to send an email to a X person with some details in the app.

I'm using the following code. I don't want to use the MessageUI because I want to send mail directly without showing the mail composer.

```
 NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:pradeep@gmail.com?&subject=Results&body=Check Out your Results here=%@",score];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

But it fails with `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`. Can anyone let me know how to solve it?

Comment: Hi the actual code is:
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"smtp.zicmail.yahoo.com//username:pradeep@gmail.com&password:****&mailto:pradeep@yahoo.com&subject=Results&body=Check Out your Results here=%@",score];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
    }
Yes the score is an Object that i want to send to the customer

Answer (score 1):

You can't send the mail without the mail composer. The way you are trying to do it will open the mail app and show the user the mail filed in with all the detail give in the mail link.

The only way to do what you want it to either have a webservice which handels the mail of implement SMTP in your app. You will need ask to user for there SMTP setting so a webservice might be the best way.

Comment: Hi Rckoenes! Can we send the message at least to the email is so how is it possible?

Comment: @Kumar it really hard to understand what you mean. Just to be clear you can't send an email via the iOS SDK without the user knowing about it. Either use the [`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) or the `mailto:` link and ask the system to open it. In both cases the OS will present a mail compose view to the user.